# Do I have to fetch in a bare repository

Tags: git

I have set up a remote bare repository following exactly this process: http://devlicio.us/blogs/krzysztof_kozmic/archive/2011/08/20/simple-guide-to-running-git-server-on-windows-in-local-network-kind-of.aspx

Now if someone else joins the project, I expect that they can just clone from this remote (on a server) repository and no we're all connected in a stable manner?

My question is if either of us push changes (i.e. from our respective local repositories), does someone have to go to this bare repository and manually call fetch, or will the pushed changes automatically make their way onto the server.

The reason I ask is that the server with the bare repository gets regular offsite backups. So all I'm asking is if as soon as I push from my local repository, the files are safely on the server's bare repository (thus enjoying offsite backups) *WITHOUT* anyone fetching or pulling?

Comment: Note this is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914961/do-i-have-to-fetch-in-my-bare-repository/25934830?noredirect=1#comment40601327_25934830 but I am splitting up the original and will soon delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dan - as soon as `git push` returns without error whatever remote you pushed to will have any refs you pushed, as well as any objects reachable by that ref (commits, trees, blobs, etc.).  This is easy to verify yourself by simply doing a push, and then making a new clone of the repo and seeing what you get.

If you have multiple refs with work on them locally, it is up to you to manage how/when you push them.